# No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error in Flask WebApp using CORS

Tags: python, flask, cors

The following code runs fine on my Windows machine, but gives me an error on my Mac when running the web app via Chrome.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS  # Import CORS
import pandas as pd
import json

from filterPlayers import filter_players
from rankPlayers import find_players

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/api/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    try:
        # Get the uploaded file from the request
        # Logic to parse uploaded excel file on webapp
```

Error message in my console:

> :8080/#/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've done some googling about the problem and the main message is that the problem should be fixed by adding the CORS package to handle the cross server request logic. I also don't understand why the code works fine, when I run it on one machine vs another.

I've also tried explicitly setting the origin to only include one domain instead of all wildcard `*` paths such as this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:8080")
```

But I get the same error.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant client code.

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I've been able to resolve the error:

"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

by completely turning off web setting in chrome via running this command:
open -na Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/temporary-chrome-profile-dir --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials.

While this leads to a different error, I consider this issue closed.